# Why is this method (setRefreshToken) undefined?

Tags: java, methods, import, undefined, spotify

this is the error "The method setRefreshToken(String) is undefined for the type String"

Music.java, which SpotifyApi.java is imported to:

```
SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi.Builder()
                .setClientId(this.id)
                .setClientSecret(this.secret)
                .setRedirectUri(myAccount)
                .build();
        spotifyApi
            .setAccessToken("<your_access_token>")
            .setRefreshToken("<your_refresh_token>")
            .build();
    }
}
```

SpotifyApi.java:

```
  public void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken) {
    this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
  }
```

Comment: because that method is in `SpotifyApi` and not `String`, for which it is apparently being called; probably `setAccessToken` is returning a `Sting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks strange.

`SpotifyApi` has methods `setAccessToken()` and `setRefreshToken()`, but both methods are `void` methods (i.e they don't return anything, so method chaining is not possible). And `SpotifyApi` has no `build()` method, so...

Maybe you meant to write:

```
SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi.Builder()
        .setClientId(this.id)
        .setClientSecret(this.secret)
        .setRedirectUri(myAccount)
        .setAccessToken("<your_access_token>")
        .setRefreshToken("<your_refresh_token>")
        .build();
```

Otherwise, you could rewrite your code as:

```
SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi.Builder()
        .setClientId(this.id)
        .setClientSecret(this.secret)
        .setRedirectUri(myAccount)
        .build();

spotifyApi.setAccessToken("<your_access_token>");
spotifyApi.setRefreshToken("<your_refresh_token>");
```